# How to change PlotLabel after plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Okey, so I have this code that took super long time to plot. It's a density plot and let's say that I would like to change to position of the `BarLegend` of the plot. I want to do this without having to redo the plot

As an example. Let's say we have the plot

```
p1 = DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -2, 2},
  ImageSize -> {600, 200},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic,
     LegendMarkerSize -> {550, 30}
     ], Above]
  ]
```

and I want the `BarLegend` below instead of above the plot. How can I do this after the plot?

I've tried various methods

```
p1 /. PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic,
LegendMargins -> {{0, 20}, {-15, 0}},
LegendMarkerSize -> {500, 30}
], Below]
```

and

```
Show[p1, PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic,
LegendMargins -> {{0, 20}, {-15, 0}},
LegendMarkerSize -> {500, 30}
], Below]]
```

Nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p1 /. Placed[a_, Above, b_] :> Placed[a, Below, b]
```

or (a bit more robust)

```
ReplacePart[p1, {-1, 2} -> Below]
```

General hint: Apply `InputForm` onto the graphics object `p1` in order figure out what exactly to replace.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I determine the coordinates of the thing that I want to change using InputForm? Like How did you know InputForm[p1][[-1,2,2]] corresponded to Above?

Comment: I knew that legends get wrapped by `Placed` and appear as second in `Legended` expressions. From where I anticipated that? I really looked at the output of `InputForm[p1]`... Also `Hold /@ p1` would have helped... After seeing that it is about an `Above`, we can find its position with `Position[p1, Above]`.

Answer (score 2):

If `Above` appears only in relation to `PlotLegends` in `p1`:

```
p1 /. Above -> Below (* or *)
Block[{Above = Below}, p1]
```

[image]